# Cursor movement too fast for code to read

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flashdevelop, mousemove

I have created a MOUSE_MOVE MouseEvent and a code to draw circles while I move the mouse cursor. The problem is, it doesn't draw out every single circle if I move the mouse too fast. 
[image: After I move the mouse cursor in a line with moderate speed]

Here are the codes I have for the MOUSE_MOVE event.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mCursor);

public function mCursor(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    var cursor:Shape = new Shape();

    cursor.graphics.beginFill(1, 1);
    cursor.graphics.drawCircle(e.stageX, e.stageY, 10);
    cursor.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(cursor);
}
```

Would there be an arithmetic equation or physics formula to have it add every single circle such that it can draw a straight line without the blanks in between?

Comment: Try using pixels (bitmap data) not Shape when making a drawing app. All these `addChild(cursor);` could slow down the system if you add too many into memory.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for using bitmap data? I'm not too familiar with it as Shape is basic to understand

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. Your problem currently is `cursor` is a variable. Every Shape added is creating multiple **variables** in the system. Create a single empty bitmapdata of specific width & height and then use setpixel (which just changes colours at specific coordinates in canvas) that way you're not constantly adding into but simply editing a set amount. If you need that specific circle shape/size then maybe first `draw` it as some `cursor_BMP` then "rubberstamp" those pixels around your `canvas_BMP`.

Comment: Look for bitmapdata tutorials on Google. First read about pixels (get familiar with concept), then look at basic AS3 **setpixel tutorial** then look for a "stamp" AS3 tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I'll investigate and study bitmapdata and pixels. I just want to be able to draw and I figured using a circle would look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
cursor.graphics.lineTo(…);
```

To draw a continuous line between points instead of adding discrete individual circles.

> I erased the above codes and just added this one line of code `cursor.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);` I tested it and there were blanks in between

You have to set the line width first by calling `lineStyle()` method of the `graphics` object. Otherwise the line width is zero (its default value).

Here's a full working document class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Shape;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var cursor:Shape;

        public function Main() 
        {
            cursor = new Shape();
            cursor.graphics.lineStyle(2);
            addChild(cursor);            

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mCursor);
        }

        private function mCursor(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            cursor.graphics.lineTo(e.stageX, e.stageY);
        }      
    }
}
```

You likely have to fiddle around with `moveTo` in order to set an appropriate starting position. As the code is now, it starts at `0/0`.

Comment: I tried using this code but the result was still the same, I got blanks in between the line I was drawing

Comment: @Zulu how exactly did you do that? Feel free to add your code to your question. For the line, you should only use one cursor object.

Comment: I erased the above codes and just added this one line of code

     mouseClick.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);

I tested it and there were blanks in between

Comment: cursor.graphics.lineTo(e.localX, e.localY);

Comment: @Zulu not exactly sure what you mean. If you only use `lineTo`, you will not see anything, if the `lineStyle` is not set. Not sure how you managed to get gaps again. I expanded my answer and included a working example code.

Comment: Oh it works! Thanks! However, how come whenever I start drawing, there will always be a line drawn from (0,0)?

http://imgur.com/a/rLNGI

I saved a screenshot for reference. I copied your code directly

Comment: @Zulu please pay attention to the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was panicking as I thought my codes became spaghetti. I thought lineTo would have had some sort of unique property but alas, moveTo!